# Как элементу списка ListView присвоить ссылку на сайт?

Tags: android, listview, строки, link

Есть список ListView. Как каждому элементу присвоить ссылку на сайт? Элементы списка записаны в strings

```
public class Cantacts extends ListFragment {
private List<ListViewItem> mItems;
public Cantacts(){}// ListView items list

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // initialize the items list
    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(getString(R.string.contacts1)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(getString(R.string.contacts2)));



    // initialize and set the list adapter
    setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}


public class ListViewItem {
    public final String description;        // the text for the ListView item title

    public ListViewItem(String description) {

        this.description = description;

    }
}

public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragments_for_tabs, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_for_tabs, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);

        return convertView;
    }


    public  class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvDescription;
    }
}
```

Файл разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!-- the description view -->

    <bogdan.derij.barmenfriend.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        customAttrs:customFont="roboto_thin" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1. Действительно ли весь этот Java код относится к вопросу? 2. Зачем указан файл разметки? 3. Откуда берутся ссылки на сайт?

Comment: вставил код Java, чтоб видели как формируется список. 2. аналогично. 3. я не знаю где писать ссылки и как сделать их рабочими

Comment: Присутствие всего кода лучше, чем вообще его отсутствие, но всё же пример [должен быть кратким](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Хотя бы для того, что долго не искать действительно нужный участок кода. По поводу того, как сделать, чтобы строка стала ссылкой, могу лишь предложить [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource), [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable?rq=1) и прочие связанные с ними.

Comment: спасибо. видел пример) и не один, но не пойму как применить его у меня в коде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Добавьте в ListViewItem поле, в котором будет храниться ссылка на сайт

```
public class ListViewItem {
    public final String description; 
    public final String url;       

    public ListViewItem(String description, String url) {

        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;

    }
}
```

2) Передавайте вторым параметром ссылку в конструктор

```
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(getString(R.string.contacts1), "http://ссылка1"));
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(getString(R.string.contacts2), "http://ссылка2"));
```

3) Элементу списка *присвоить* можно только другой элемент списка, т. к. Java - язык строгой типизации. Если в переводе на нормальный язык *присвоить* значит *открывать по нажатии*, то нужно установить `OnItemClickListener` вашему `ListView`, в котором вытаскивать ссылку у элемента списка, и открывать ее.

Comment: спасибо. не могли бы Вы дописать с OnItemClickListener? пожалуйста)

Comment: @bodia7 нет, я итак за вас много вашей работы сделал

Comment: все равно спасибо